# How could I know that BeginAcceptSocket callback needs IAsyncResult parameter?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I am curious where can I find out that AcceptClient as a callback of BeginAcceptSocket needs to have IAsyncResult as a parameter. In the MSDN article there is only mentioned that return value of BeginAcceptSocket is IAsyncresult. But how could I know that it has to be passed to callback?
Thanks!

```
     public server(int port)
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port);
        listener.BeginAcceptSocket(this.AcceptClient,null);

    }
    private void AcceptClient(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [its documentation,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginacceptsocket.aspx) you know that [`BeginAcceptSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginacceptsocket.aspx) expects an `AsyncCallback` as its first parameter, so the next step is to read [the documentation for the `AsyncCallback` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx), which is itself a type with the following method signature:

```
public delegate void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginacceptsocket.aspx

The parameters section tells you that the first parameter expects a System.AsyncCallback, which is a delegate that expects an argument of type System.IAsyncResult.

Comment: But there is not said that AsyncCallback expects IAsyncResult

Comment: The first parameter of the AsyncCallback delegate is an IAsyncResult.